# Show token username symfony2 in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to display the username of the logged in user in my twig template.

Setting token, which works perfect with firewalls and logs the user in:

```
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword(), "secured_area", $user->getRoles());
            $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
            $session->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));
```

I want to put something like:

```
<div class='meta'>Logged in as <b>username_here</b>
```

at the top of my template.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under normal circumstances you should be able to display the username by writting this line:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

Just in case I didn't get the question right or didn't understand what you have there is also an alternative. **Note** what was also mentioned in the comments by @Tsounable. This alternative is deprecated since version 2.6 and shouldn't be used anymore!

```
{{ app.security.getToken().getUser().getUsername() }}
```

Not sure what works out for you. The former is the kind of "standard" way to achieve what you want.

Comment: app.security method is deprecated since version 2.6. Use app.user instead.

Comment: Thank you, I added a note to my original post